# update query not working c# winform

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

My data is not being updated in database table. This is my code

```
string marks = textBox1.Text.ToString() + "," + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "," + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "," + textBox4.Text.ToString() + "," + textBox5.Text.ToString();
string subjects = label5.Text.ToString() + "," + label6.Text.ToString() + "," + label7.Text.ToString() + "," + label8.Text.ToString() + "," + label9.Text.ToString();
string total = label11.Text.ToString();
string percentage = label13.Text.ToString();
string id = textBox1.Text.ToString();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\TECHNOGEEKZ\Desktop\USSv0.1\USSv0.1\USSv0.1\db\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    string q = "UPDATE marks SET subjects='" + subjects + "',smarks='" + marks + "',percentage='" + percentage + "',total='" + total + "' WHERE idno='" + id + "'";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Marks have been updated");
```

}

This is my table where I want to update data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[marks] 
(
    [Id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [idno]       INT           NULL,
    [subjects]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [smarks]     VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [percentage] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [total]      VARCHAR (50)  NULL
);
```

Comment: Please debug and check what `q` (your query) finally looks like. This code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)! Please use **parameterized queries instead of inserting user input directly into your query string!**

Comment: And the error at hand is: `WHERE idno='" + id + "'` The `Id` column is of type `int` so no quotations marks around `id` needed.

Comment: I changed it to  WHERE idno=" + id + ""; still it is not updating.When I run this query individually in SQL it updates the data. The double quotes are for query. I removed the single quotes which determines a string/varchar type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks, either intentionally or unintentionally. It could be causing your error, depending on what the values are in the concatenated strings.

Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`and are `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. The `if` test should be redundant, since Open will complain if it fails. All of the ToString methods being called on the Text properties are redundant as they are already strings. Consider adding a tag for [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) to this question, to target the right expertise.

Answer (score 0):

you are using this query

```
    "UPDATE marks SET subjects='" + subjects + "',smarks='" + marks + "',percentage='" + percentage + "',total='" + total + "' WHERE idno='" + id + "'";
```

here you are using '' in id also whereas usually id is of integer datatype. So id will not be there in the quotes. Also check your final query and run that final query in mssql. That will not bcause of this error.